# PHP SOAP Request to send multiple elements

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am attempting to subscribe to a web service using PHP Soap client. My PHP code does successfully reach the web service but does not pass all the needed elements to subscribe. I have tried two different PHP documents with identical results. My code is based on the following link https://devzone.zend.com/2202/php-and-soap-first-steps/. I used SoapUi to parse the wsdl and the subscribe function is formatted as

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ass="http://assignment.soap.assignshare" xmlns:xsd="http://request.assignment.soap.assignshare/xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ass:Subscribe>
         <ass:SasReqSubscribe>
            <xsd:Source>VendorC</xsd:Source>
            <xsd:Dest>http://192.168.50.3:26001/SAIWebService</xsd:Dest>
            <xsd:MsgTag>1</xsd:MsgTag>
            <xsd:SupportsPendingAssignments>false</xsd:SupportsPendingAssignments>
            <xsd:AppVersion>AppVersion</xsd:AppVersion>
            <xsd:ProtocolVersion>1.20</xsd:ProtocolVersion>
            <xsd:SubscriptionPort>http://localhost:26001/SAIWebService</xsd:SubscriptionPort>
         </ass:SasReqSubscribe>
      </ass:Subscribe>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am trying to create the sae result using PHP Soap. My First PHP code is as follows.

```
    $wsdl = "http://192.168.50.3:26001/SAIWebservice?singlewsdl";

    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(
                            "trace"=>1,
                            "exceptions"=>0));

    $name7 = "http://xx.xxx.183.202:8080";*/

    $parameters= array("Source"=>'Test',"Dest"=>'http://192.168.50.3:26001/SAIWebService',"MsgTag"=>1,"SupportsPendingAssignments"=>0,
    "AppVersion"=>'AppVersion,"ProtocolVersion"=>1.20,"SubscriptionPort"=>"http://xx.xxx.183.202:8080');

    $values = $client->Subscribe($parameters);

    print "<pre>\n";

    print "<br />\n Request : ".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest());

    print "<br />\n Response: ".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponse());

    print "</pre>";
```

I have used Wireshark to capture the posted XML, but the elements "Source", "Dest", "MsgTag", "SupportsPendingAssignments", "ProtocolVersion" & "SubscriptionPort" are not posted."
[WireShark Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJTRl.jpg)

Second PHP with same results

```
    $wsdl = "http://192.168.50.3:26001/SAIWebservice?singlewsdl";

    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(
                            "trace"=>1,
                            "exceptions"=>0));
    $name1 = "Test";
    $name2 = "http://192.168.50.3:26001/SAIWebService";
    $name3 = "1";
    $name4 = "false";
    $name5 = "AppVersion";
    $name6 = "1.20";
    $name7 = "http://xx.xxx.183.202:8080";

    $parameters= array("Source"=>$name1,"Dest"=>$name2,"MsgTag"=>$name3,"SupportsPendingAssignments"=>$name4,"AppVersion"=>$name5,"ProtocolVersion"=>$name6,"SubscriptionPort"=>$name7);

    $values = $client->Subscribe($parameters);

    print "<pre>\n";

    print "<br />\n Request : ".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest());

    print "<br />\n Response: ".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponse());

    print "</pre>";

?>
```

I'd appreciate any help in why the elements are not being passed in the PHP Soap client request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm used to sending parameters through soap calls as a stdclass PHP object. Not arrays. Maybe just cast the array with parameters to object with `(object)$parameters` in your `$client->subscribe` call

Comment: Thank you much! I used the stdclass object to make it work.

Comment: Could you accept the answer for the benefit of others as well?